# Value getting loaded from cache even after exceeding the cache control age limit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have cache control limit `[private; max-age=15]` set to 15 seconds in my server response. But even after 15 seconds the response is being loaded from cache. I am using `swift3` & `Alamofire 4.0`.

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)
        request.timeoutInterval = 30
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("private", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")
        request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        request.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "auth_key")

        Alamofire.request(request).responseObject(completionHandler: { (response: Response) in {
        print(response)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your caching policy.
Apple's documentation reads,

> `case returnCacheDataElseLoad` Specifies that the existing cached data
>   should be used to satisfy the request, **regardless of its age or
>   expiration date**. If there is no existing data in the cache
>   corresponding the request, the data is loaded from the originating
>   source.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy

Look at the list, and figure out what the best policy will be for you. I would suggest setting it to the default `useProtocolCachePolicy`.